# Wicket RadioGroup over multiple entitites

Tags: java, wicket

I find wicket's RadioGroup to be utterly confusing. I got n entities in a repeater, where I want to set the field "booleanvalue". So this is my code:

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup<>("someGroup", new Model(entityXYZ));
radioValue = new Radio("radioValue", 
    new PropertyModel(entityXYZ, "booleanValue"), radioGroup);
repeaterContainer.add(radioValue);
// add other stuff to repeater
```

All the examples I found don't seem to apply. I don't want a single entity in the radioGroup, but n different of which I want to allow only one to have its field set.
I tried all kinds of Model combination, none of which work.

UPDATE: It seems to be a problem with the component hierarchy. I cannot add the radioValues into the same hierarchy, as within the repeater custom user input may be added as well as other RadioGroups. Additionally, the group does not consist of a single object, but of a number of objects where only one should have the boolean value set. In HTML this is no problem, but I don't see any way to solve this in Wicket :(

Answer (score 0):

You want to update a property on a set of entities?

```
RadioGroup<Entity> group = new RadioGroup<Entity>("someGroup", new IModel<Entity>() {
  public void setObject(Entity entity) {
    for (Entity candidate : entities) {
      candidate.setBooleanValue(candidate == entity);
    }
  }
  public Entity getObject() {
    for (Entity candidate : entities) {
      if (candidate.getBooleanValue()) {
        return candidate;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
});

group.add(new ListView("entities", entities) {
  protected void populateItem(final ListItem<Entity> item)
    item.add(new Radio("radio", item.getModel());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How a radiogroup works is basically you add the radio's for every choice to the radiogroup. Then when one of those radio's is selected, the model object for the group changes to the model object from the selected radio.

See also http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/compref/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.source.SourcesPage;jsessionid=13F0ADB2C785F4A9A1C04519A050A37A?0&SourcesPage_class=org.apache.wicket.examples.compref.Index&source=RadioGroupPage.java

In essence:

```
RadioGroup<SomeEntity> group = new RadioGroup<SomeEntity>("somegroup", new Model<Entity>(null));

group.add(new Radio("choice1", new Model<SomeEntity>(someEntityA));
group.add(new Radio("choice2", new Model<SomeEntity>(someEntityB));

form.add(group);
```

Then in the form submit you could do:

```
SomeEntity selectedEntity = group.getModelObject();
```